# type name bool not allowed. c++

Tags: c++

There are four errors that show; i understand none of them.

> Error 1: type name not allowed                   line 11.
>
> Error 2: expected a ','                          line 11(after bool).
>
> Error 3: expected a '}'                          line 11(after true).
>
> Error 4: expected a declaration                  line 12(before for).

I am a novice programmer and i kind of have o idea what i'm doing; so please help. Here's  the code:

```
      #include "stdafx.h"
      #include <iostream>
      using namespace std;
    1 int main{ 
    2 bool alternate = true ;
    3 for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    4 {
    5   for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    6   {
    7       if (alternate)
    8       {
    9           cout << "X ";
   10           cout << "O ";
   11
   12       }
   13       else
   14       {
   15           cout << "O ";
   16           cout << "X ";
   17
   18       }
   19   }
   20   alternate = !alternate;
   21
   22   cout << endl;
   23 }
   24 }
```

Comment: error 1 is at line 2......error 2 is at line 2........error 3 is at line 3...........error 4 is at line 3........... thank u.

Comment: `main` is a function but you are declaring it as if it is a variable. Essentially, you are missing parenthesis. Once that is fixed the code should compile.

Comment: It's `main() {`

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to get help with the first steps of learning to program in a language. There's a million other resources out there for that. Although error messages can sometimes be cryptic, especially for a new user, you have to reduce the complexity until you understand. Have you compiled a "hello world" program before you tried this code? If so, you should understand the function "main" and function declarations. If not, you are trying to walk before you can crawl.

Comment: Don't put line numbers in code that you're posting. Especially not line numbers that are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

main is a function, so you should declare it as:

```
int main() {...
```

The 
 #include "stdafx.h" is microsoft specific and won't compile on other platforms.
stdafx.h is not necessary for this code to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've just missed some Syntax in the above code. The correct code is :

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
       bool alternate = true ;
       for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
       {
         for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
         {
            if (alternate)
            {
               cout << "X ";
               cout << "O ";

            }
            else
            {
              cout << "O ";
              cout << "X ";

            }
         }
        alternate = !alternate;
        cout << endl;
      }
      return 0;
   }
```

The mistake in your code was that you missed "()" after the main method. Also, you forgot to write the return statement.

Comment: The main function doesn't need a `return`. If control reaches the end of main the effect is the same as executing `return 0;`

Comment: @Blastfurnace,
I agree with you but for beginners, it's good to have the habit of writing return statement.

Also, you will get errors in Visual Studio if you don't write return statements.

Comment: I don't think we should invent language rules that aren't in the standard. If we're concerned about missing `return` statements then tell beginners to turn up their compiler warning level. I just checked with Visual Studio 2017 and main without a `return` emits no warnings or errors even at level /Wall

Comment: `error C4716: 'main' : must return a value`
This is the error statement in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you compiling a C++ source file? I can't reproduce your error.